# How do I call neo4j apoc functions using .net

Tags: .net, neo4j, neo4jclient, neo4j-apoc

Nodes :

```
Template -> Id =1 , Name = T1;
Segment -> Id =1 , Name = S1;
Segment -> Id =2 , Name = S2;
```

Relationships :

```
T1 - [r1:REL] -> S1;
T1 - [r2:REL] -> S2
```

Each relationship ( r1 and r2) has a property called LineIds which are integer array.
Therefore, r1.LineIds = [1,3] and 
r2.LineIds = [1,2]

I am trying to get the intersection of both the LineIds.

I am trying to call apoc.coll.intersection() function using .Net driver Neo4jClient but it is throwing some or the other error.
However, It is working in Neo4j Browser like

```
match (:Template)- [r1:REL] -> (m:Segment), (:Template) - [r2:REL] -> (n:Segment)
return apoc.coll.intersection(r1.LineIds, r2.LineIds) as result
```

Can somebody tell me the correct syntax in .net?

Comment: Show your .NET code and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You just call `apoc` the same way you call any other function:

```
var query = client.Cypher
    .Match("(:Template)-[r1:REL]->(m:Segment), (:Template)-[r2:REL]->(n:Segment)")
    .Return(() => new
    {
        result = Return.As <IEnumerable<int>> ("apoc.coll.intersection(r1.LineIds, r2.LineIds)")
    });

foreach(var result in query.Results)
{
    /* Do something here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That actually worked very well. Also, what if I have more than two list to get the intersection from? How do I proceed in such case as apoc.coll.intersection only expects 2 arguments? Can you please let me know the syntax?

Comment: You'll have to play around, my first guess would be to call intersection passing in the result of the other intersection, but I've not tested it. Try it and see, if you can't figure it out, add a new question with what you've tried and some sample data and someone should be able to help!

Comment: Yeah I did, finally figured it out. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good I'm glad you got it sorted! You should accept answers if they've helped, so they might help others later on